# Spring MVC html encoding utf8 does not display russion letters

Tags: html, spring-mvc, encoding

I'm using idea and I setted the settings:
[image]

and the settings:
[image]

And result of this:
[image]

What else it wants from me?

PS: encoding of html file is UTF8 as evidenced by the inscription UTF-8 at the bottom of the html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Thymeleaf and the problem was in the view resolver config. I did add the following settings:

viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

and

templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");